# What can I use to keep track of my web research?

Tags: web-browser, project-management, search-engine

I occasionally take on big ‪‎web research‬ projects and I typically find them frustrating. It seems like a good browser plug-in could help alleviate some of that frustration.

Currently I'm considering writing a practical book on intermediate level competition robot navigation. But before investing months in a project like that, I feel like I need to know if such a book already exists. I need to do a fairly exhaustive web search.

I've taken on ‪online research‬ projects like this before, and it's always been difficult. My memory and attention span get heavily taxed after reading endless webpages on vaguely related topics for several days.  I'm imagining that there exists a browser plug-in that helps keep track of what I've read and what my impressions were.  It would also be nice to be able to see how I found a certain site and keep track of what sites I want to go back to and why.

If anyone knows of any software, or browser plug-in, that serves that purpose I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Chrome extension that I can use to note why I've opened a tab?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/is-there-a-chrome-extension-that-i-can-use-to-note-why-ive-opened-a-tab)

Comment: I checked out that page, and as I was installing AnnoTabe I discovered Hypothesis.  It's a collaborative annotation tool for webpages.  Seems pretty promising.  Thanks, that's got me started.